# extend c drive in vmware machine

Tags: vmware, extend

i'm trying to extend the C drive storage , but the option is greyed out ,any help please ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAdh3.png)

Comment: Similar questions [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32497/extend-system-drive-c-partition-in-windows-10) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1509186/extend-system-partition-windows-10) were asked in other site, System partition `cannot` be extended using `Disk Management`